# Gesture recognition JavaScript library

Tags: events, javascript, gesture

I'm developing a mobile website and would like to add gesture recognition to some of the key features of the site.

Is there a suitable javascript library that would allow me to draw a gesture and recognise the gesture as a token I could hook up to an event call?

As an example of this type of functionality in Dolphin see these links;

[image: Gesture configuration]

And the video:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k73ipSDZJXM

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one: http://taitems.tumblr.com/post/2785024873/javascript-gesture-recognition-for-touch-screens
And: https://github.com/plainview/Jester/

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I'm looking for. Once I test that I can create new tokens sufficiently I'll return and mark your answer correct.

Comment: On a sidenote, I got these links by just googling for 'Gesture recognition JavaScript library' (your question's title). These were the 1st two links along with this page. So do google before asking the question :)

Comment: I did do plenty of Googling and visiting of webappers.com and the like. Sometimes it's just the terms you use at the end of the day.

Answer (score 4):

We're using [Hammer.js](http://eightmedia.github.com/hammer.js/) and it is working great.

"Can't touch this".  -- MC Hammer
(See what they did there?)
[image: MC Hammer]

Answer (score 4):

For simple gesture recognition, there's [$1](http://depts.washington.edu/aimgroup/proj/dollar/). It's less than 100 lines of code and is written in JS.